# Как сделать проверки на правильность введённых данных?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не знаю как правильно сделать проверки на правильность введённых данных. Если введено не число или если в цвет введена не строчка цвета или если один из пунктов пропущен, то нужно включать блок "warning". Но то, что я делал не работает даже на числа. Кто подскажет? Нужно ипользовать только js.

```js
function getId(a)
{
 return document.getElementById(a);
}
getId('createTable').onclick = function()
{
 let trTable = getId('rowElementsTable').value;
 let tdTable = getId('colElementsTable').value;
 let widthTable = getId('widthTable').value;
 let heightTable = getId('heightTable').value;
 let cellspacing = getId('cellspacing').value;
 let weightTable = getId('weightTable').value;
 let colorLine = getId('colorLine').value;

 if (isNaN(trTable) || isNaN(tdTable) || isNaN(widthTable) || isNan(heightTable) || isNan(cellspacing) || isNaN(weightTable))
 {
  getId('warning').style.display = 'block';
  getId('tableBox').style.left = '50%';
  getId('tableBox').style.transform = 'scale(1)';
 }

}
```

```css
#tableBox
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 350px;
 height: 160px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -80px;
 margin-left: -175px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 6px 20px black;
 z-index: 9999;
 transform: scale(1);
 transition: 1s;
}

#rowElementsTable,
#colElementsTable,
#widthTable,
#heightTable,
#cellspacing,
#weightTable,
#colorLine
{
 width: 50px;
 outline: none;
}

#formTable
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
}

.overflowTable
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 z-index: 9998;
}

#warning
{
 color: red;
 font-size: 14px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableBox">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>К-сть рядків:</td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="rowElementsTable"> </td>
   <td>К-сть стовбців:</td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="colElementsTable"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Ширина:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="widthTable"> </td>
     <td>Висота:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="heightTable"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>cellspacing:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="cellspacing"> </td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Товщина рамки:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="weightTable"> </td>
     <td>Колір рамки:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="colorLine"> </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 <p id="warning">Дані введено не коректно або не всі поля заповнені</p>
 <form id="formTable">
  <input type="button" value="Скинути" id="deleteValue">
  <input type="button" value="Створити" id="createTable">
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть готовые решения, используйте jQuery, его расширения валидации и маски, к примеру вот [этот](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)

Comment: Что вам показывают: `console.log(isNaN(trTable));` `console.log(isNaN(tdTable));` и т.д.?

Comment: если текст в первом инпуте то работает если и текст и числа то нет и если все ввести верно то не работает кнопка создания
 else{...} прописал